# Getting input by name and not by index

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

HTML snippet:

```
  <input type='hidden' name='id' value='default' />
```

I'm using WWW::Mechanize to fill in a form, an input of which is above. I'm doing this:

```
$inputs[0]->value("nondefault");
```

since it's the first input in the form. But is there a way to refer to it as `id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aForm),

```
$form->param('id', 'nondefault');
```